# Non-matching routes are rendered with React Router

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

I'm using React Router with TypeScript.  Here's two routes, namely `/` and `/pages/id`.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component
{
    render()
    {
        return <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <Route exact path='/' children={
                () =>
                <TopPage />} />
            <Route exact path='/pages/:id' children={
                (props: RouteComponentProps<{id: string}>) =>{
                    console.log(props)
                    return <IndividualPage match={props.match} />}} />
        </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    }
}
```

I expect, since my `Route`s are `exact`:

- when I access `/`, only `TopPage` component is rendered
- when I access `/pages/1`, only `IndividualPage` component is rendered
- when I access `/no-pages`, nothing is rendered

However, I observed:

- when I access `/`, or `/no-pages`, `IndividualPage` component is rendered with `match=null` (causing `Cannot read property 'params' of null` error)
- when I access `/pages/1`, both `TopPage` and `IndividualPage` components are rendered

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you add children on your root ?

Comment: What part of my codn do you mean by "add children on your root"? My understanding is that a `Router` should have `Route`s as children and a `Route` should have a function component (which I made from my class components by function expression) as `children` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are four different ways to set the render component for a `Route`, some of which behave slightly differently than others.  Setting the `children` prop to a render function is one of those ways, but it's not the one that you want based on the behavior you expect.  Unlike the other methods, the contents of a `children` function are **always** rendered even if the current page is not a match.  So you will have both components rendering on every page.  Per [the docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/children-func):

> Sometimes you need to render whether the path matches the location or not. In these cases, you can use the function children prop. It works exactly like render except that it gets called whether there is a match or not.

Instead you can use the [`render` prop](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func) or the [`component` prop](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/component).  These will only render if the route is a match.

The default behavior of the `Router` is to render all `Routes` which match, not just the first.  In practice, this is a non-issue with your example because you have two `exact` routes so there is no possibility that both will match.  But as a habit I would recommend putting your `Route` components inside of a [`Switch` component](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch) which will only render the first matching `Route`.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={TopPage} />
          <Route exact path="/pages/:id" component={IndividualPage} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

No typescript annotations are needed here because the `Route` component knows that `RouteComponentProps` will be passed to the component.